# AWS x-ray not generating

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-xray

I am trying to generate an x-ray using aws x-ray but it is not generating. Currently I am generating it for a lambda function in node.js

```
async function geUser(event, context) {

    await someFunction();
    const segment = new AWSXRay.Segment('getUser');
    segment.close();
    return 'success';
};
```

I have tried below example but still it's not generating

```
async function getUser(event, context) {

    await someFunction();
    AWSXRay.captureFunc('annotations', function(subsegment){
        console.log('xraysubsegment', subsegment);
        subsegment.addAnnotation('LambdaFunction', 'getUser');
        subsegment.addAnnotation('UserID', id);
    });
    return 'success';
};
```

and in serverless.yml

```
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow" 
      Action:
        - "xray:PutTraceSegments"
        - "xray:PutTelemetryRecords"
      Resource: "*"
```

Is there anything I am missing

Answer (score 0):

To use X-Ray in a Lambda function, you need to enable X-Ray for that Lambda function.
In the console this is done under the "Debuggin and error handling configuration section", the configuration is called "Enable active tracing".

See [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/enabling-x-ray.html) for further details.

Comment: I need to understand one thing, it means that the code will work after checking the "Enable active tracing", or will the aws will add the tracing on its own?

Comment: I would say so, but I haven't tried it with nodejs yet